# what is ado.net

Tags: ado.net

I am to join a new company and was asked if I can use ado.net. They asked me to tell them the use of ado.net and what are the special purposes?

Comment: See http://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+ado.net

Comment: @Reno: please don't post .NET 1.1 links.

Comment: @John okay ... is it because MS changes it links often?

Comment: @Reno: no, it's because that was a .NET 1.1 link, and .NET 1.1 is almost a decade old. Using the link without the parentheses should always return the latest version.

Comment: @John I know that, hmm my bad,  I think there was a drop down on that page to get the newer version of the page. I was just not impressed by the quality of this question. Perhaps we should close (or merge) this as dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598699/what-is-ado-net)?

Answer (score 7):

ADO.NET is Active Data Objects for .NET. Its used to access different data sources (databases, etc..) from within .NET. We were taught to use it to query SQL Server databases where I went to college.

You can find a decent tutorial [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx) or you can learn to [get started with it](http://devcity.net/articles/14/start_ado_net.aspx) at that link.

Comment: ADO.Net stands for Active Data Objects, please dont confuse newbies  with ADODB and old ActiveX (unmanaged code) technologies.

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, muscle memory just had to hit that X after the word active. Edited for correctness, thanks.