# ADO.NET: Getting data from 1 table to another?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net, sqlcommand

Does anyone know or have an example of getting data from 1 table to another?

it is using an SQL SERVER EXPRESS, and 2 tables are practically the same, 1 was used as a temporary table by a fronend client.. so my backend client needs to move items from the temp tables to my other tables.

Do I need to use a forward only cursor and a for loop?

I presume i open a connection, use a command object to query the database that would come back to a `DataSet`?

I iterate over the for loop and call insert records using the `COMMAND` object of `ADO.NET`

Is there not a better way of doing it ?

Comment: Look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3598699/1668398

Comment: quesiton updated with db type etc

Answer (score 2):

If the columns of the two tables are the same:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1
SELECT * FROM TABLE_2
```

If not all the columns are the same, you can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (common_column1, common_column2, common_column3)
SELECT common_column1, common_column2, common_column3 FROM TABLE_2
```

After that you can update the columns that are not equal.
Or you can insert a hardcoded value on the columns that aren't equal:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (common_column1, common_column2, common_column3, diff_column_1, diff_column_2)
SELECT common_column1, common_column2, common_column3, '1', '2' FROM TABLE_2
```

Comment: no they are not exactly the same, well some are but there destination table has more fields which i will need to update

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in SQL only, something like:

```
SELECT *
INTO theNewTable
FROM FirstTable dept
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Put into a strored procedure or execute it directly as a command.

**Note that:** the [`INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) will creates a new table with the same structure as the first one and copy all the rows from the first table into it. If you want to create only the table not to populate the rows and copy them into the new created table us a always-falsy expression. for example "1 = 0".

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `DataTable.Copy`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx

You can also use `DataTable.ImportRow`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx

TSQL : You can also use : `INSERT SELECT` query  in stored procedure.

Comment: nice, but my tables are not exactly the same and the destination will have more fields which i must update manaully.

Comment: @Martin When you use DataTable.Copy, you copy into local table, for example : var table = yourDataTable.Copy(); so you cpy structure and datas. you can also try with Clone and Import Row. you can also execute stored procedure, and adjust your query

Answer (score 0):

You can insert data using this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (columnname1, columnname2, columnname3,.....)
SELECT columnname1, columnname2, columnname3 FROM TBL
```